# Multivariate Time Series Analysis using Python-LSTM

Tags: lstm

I am new to Time Series and need some help from subject experts. So I had a lab data with 11 variables, reported with respect to time. the 10 variables were controllable, and the 11th variable was output. I have used LSTM to forecast time series for 11th variable. The results are way better than expectations. The 11th variable was forecasted with 0.001 RMSE. The training data had 5000 samples and test data had 4599. I am happy with forecasting. Now I need to perform analysis about how the input 10 variables are impacting the 11th output variable. Please suggest a good library, tutorial with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the  best approach here is to change your model architecture to enable transparency:
I am a big fan of attention mechanism and just recently posted an answer to a related question on the IMDB dataset - it should be straightforward for you to obtain similar outputs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481366/9487195

If this is not acceptable I am afraid you are quite out of luck since I am not aware of any robust research (moreover library) for analysis of RNN preds that doesn't modify architecture of the net.